# How do I 'see' an external USB drive connected directly to my Broadband Router?

Tags: usb, drive

This is a very frustrating problem!  I have a small home network with several dual boot Ubuntu / Windows computers.  I have recently upgraded my Broadband connection and the new router permits the direct attachment of an external USB drive which can back up all of the household's computers.

There are no problems when booted under Windows, and there were no problems with older versions of UBUNTU, but since upgrading to 11.10 I can no longer "see" the drive.  I used to find it via Network / Windows Network / Home / name of Router, but under 11.10 the same method yields an error message `Unable to mount location Failed to retrieve share list from server`.

Can anyone help please?

```
Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-12-21 10:06 GMT

Stats: 0:02:02 elapsed; 0 hosts completed (1 up), 1 undergoing Service Scan

Service scan Timing: About 50.00% done; ETC: 10:10 (0:01:56 remaining)

Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.254

Host is up (0.0097s latency).

Not shown: 998 filtered ports

PORT     STATE SERVICE     VERSION

554/tcp  open  rtsp?

7070/tcp open  realserver?



Service detection performed. Please report any incorrect results at http://nmap.org/submit/ .

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 152.38 seconds
sudo tail -n 30 /var/log/syslog

[sudo] password for alaric: 


Dec 21 10:05:42 UPSTAIRS2U wpa_supplicant[882]: WPA: Group rekeying completed with 00:01:3b:8b:63:1a [GTK=TKIP]
```

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you told us the make and model of your router. (Cougar Kid supplies router info, hitherto silent Knowledgeable Person slaps forehead and says "I have one of those" and supplies answer).

To see all the active nodes on your network, type `arp -an`.
One of the listed IP addresses should be your router. 
The router is the "Gateway" in the output of `netstat -rn`.
Then, to see which ports are open on the router (with IP address "$router"):

```
 sudo nmap -A -T4 $router
```

Once you know which ports are open on the router, you can proceed with the problem diagnosis.

Another approach is to:
1. Note the computer time.
2. Cause the problem to happen (do what you have to do to cause the error message "Unable to mount location Failed to retrieve share list from server".
3. Type the command `ls -rlt /var/log` to see a list of the system's log files ordered by modification time.
4. For each of the log files with a time later that the Step 1 time, do `sudo tail -n 30 /var/log/...`
5. Carefully read the log entries - they **may** contain information about the problem.

`arp` and `netstat` are from the `net-tools` package, `nmap` is from `nmap`

Comment: The router is marketed as 'BT Home Hub 3' - as supplied with BT Internet in the UK.  I suspect that it is in fact made for them by one of the 'usual suspects', but I can't find any clues anywhere.  Just to repeat, for example, there were no problems under version 10.10 or 11.04. I am studying the other points you raise now and I'll be back soon...

Comment: here is what happened:Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-12-21 10:04 GMT

Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -PN

Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 2.10 seconds

cougar@UPSTAIRS2U:~$ nmap -A -T4 -PN $192.168.1.254

Comment: Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2011-12-21 10:04 GMT

Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -PN

Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 2.10 seconds

cougar@UPSTAIRS2U:~$ nmap -A -T4 -PN $192.168.1.254

Comment: nmap has tricks it wants to do with packets, so it's best to run it as root. Try `sudo nmap -A -PN -T4 192.168.1.254`. The "$" was part of the shell variable. If you had done `router=192.168.1.254` then `sudo nmap -A -PN -T4 $router` would have been equivalent to `sudo nmap -A -PN -T4 192.168.1.254`.

Comment: Have you looked at **http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BT_Home_Hub**? It claims that the disk must be FAT32 formatted.   

Have you read the documents on **http://bt.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/32813/~/bt-home-hub-3**?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments - PROBLEM SOLVED!!!  In Nautilus hover at the top of the screen to reveal the menu bar, choose 'Go' and 'Location' and type in smb://{IP address}/{device name} and hey it works!  I have bookmarked the location to simplify life.  Thanks for the clues in your comments